# PDOException Modificación del mensaje

Tags: php, pdo

Estoy realizando un CRUD, y estoy dando los últimos coletazos para su finalización, pues el tema es, por ejemplo si en una de las tablas metemos una PK duplicada lanza este error por el PDOException:

```
SQLSTATE: 23000 (ER_DUP_KEY)
```

Pero claro, quisiera saber si hubiera alguna forma de modificar ese mensaje. Yo al ver eso se que es clave primaria duplicada, pero por ejemplo un usuario que no haya visto en su vida nada de BBDD puede que no, no se si me explico, se que si pongo un `echo` encima lo visualiza pero claro, no siempre va a ser ese el error puede haber otros.

Gracias por vuestra ayuda.

Esta seria la construcción hacia la BBDD

```
public function __CONSTRUCT() {
    try {
        $this->pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=prueba;charset=UTF8', 'root', '');
        $this->pdo->setAttribute(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND, "SET NAMES 'utf8'");
        $this->pdo->exec("SET NAMES 'utf8';");
        $this->pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        $this->pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        die($e->getMessage());
    }
}
```

Y este por ejemplo la función de insertar:

```
public function Registrar(Categoria $data) {
    try {
        $sql = "INSERT INTO categoria (acronimo,categoria,registro_calidad)
            VALUES (?, ?,?)";
//Ejecucion de la consulta siguiente
        $this->pdo->prepare($sql)->execute(array(
            $data->__GET('acronimo'),
            $data->__GET('categoria'),
            $data->__GET('registro_calidad')
                )
        );
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        die($e->getMessage());
    }
}
```

P.D. Edición del código para una última consulta realizada en la respuesta que fue asignada como valida.

```
public function __construct() {
    try {
        $this->pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=prueba;charset=UTF8', 'root', '');
        $this->pdo->setAttribute(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND, "SET NAMES 'utf8'");
        $this->pdo->exec("SET NAMES 'utf8';");
        $this->pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        $this->pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        die($this->getErrorMsg($e));
    }
}

protected function getErrorMsg(PDOException $e) {
    switch ($e->getCode()) {
        case 23000:
            //AQUI Analizar cual de todos los tipos es
            return 'Violación de restricciones de integridad';
        default:
            return $e->getMessage();
        case 25000:
            //AQUI Analizar cual de todos los tipos es
            return 'Violación de restricciones de integridad';
        default:
            return $e->getMessage();
    }
}
```

Comment: Ya que no hay código como para ver donde esta el problema y publicar una respuesta de calidad, te recomiendo que leas [`PDO: Errores y su manejo`](http://php.net/manual/es/pdo.error-handling.php#pdo.error-handling)

Comment: Editado, no me cosque de que vendría bien un poco más de código, voy a ir leyendo ese articulo gracias.

Comment: ¿Quieres poder identificar el error y enviar un propio, o solo te gustaria obtenerlo en otro idioma?

Comment: En otro idioma puede ser que estuviera mejor, para que usuarios inexpertos pudieran al menos poder identificar el tipo de error más fácilmente, ya que enviar uno propio seria con un echo por lo que pude probar pero claro los tipos de errores nunca van a ser iguales

Comment: En el método `getErrorMsg` solo debe haber un `default`. Te recomiendo leer como se usa el [`switch`](http://php.net/manual/es/control-structures.switch.php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Mensajes de error traducidos

Desde `PHP` para indicarle a `MySQL` el idioma de los mensajes de error puedes usar [`lc_messages`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/error-message-language.html)

Ejemplo:

```
SET lc_messages = 'es_ES'
```

Usando tu código, podrías hacer lo siguiente:

```
public function __CONSTRUCT() {
    try {
        $this->pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=prueba;charset=UTF8', 'root', '');
        $this->pdo->setAttribute(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND, "SET NAMES 'utf8'; SET lc_messages = 'es_ES'");
        $this->pdo->exec("SET NAMES 'utf8'; SET lc_messages = 'es_ES'");
        $this->pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        $this->pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        die($e->getMessage());
    }
}
```

### Mensajes de error personalizados

**Opción 1: Mapeo**

[`PDOException`](http://php.net/manual/es/class.pdoexception.php) provee el método [`getCode`](http://php.net/manual/es/exception.getcode.php), el cual devuelve solo el `código de la excepción`.
Si además tienes un arreglo donde mapear los errores por su código, puedes devolver un mensaje personalizado.

Ejemplo:

```
class DB
{
    private $pdo;

    public function __construct()
    {
        try {
            $this->pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=prueba;charset=UTF8', 'root', '');
            $this->pdo->setAttribute(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND, "SET NAMES 'utf8'");
            $this->pdo->exec("SET NAMES 'utf8';");
            $this->pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
            $this->pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            die($this->getErrorMsg($e));
        }
    }

    protected function getErrorMsg(PDOException $e) {
        switch ($e->getCode()) {
            case 23000:
                // AQUI Analizar cual de todos los tipos es
                return 'Violación de restricciones de integridad';
            default:
                return $e->getMessage();
        }
    }
```

**Opción 2: OOP**

- Crear tu propia clase extendida de `PDOException`, para personalizar los mensajes.
- Crear tu propia clase extendida de `PDO`, y sobreescribir los métodos `__construct`, `exec`, `query`, etc., capturar las excepciones y lanzar las personalizadas en su lugar. Utilizar esta nueva clase para conectarse a la `DB`.

Ejemplo:

```
class MyPDOException extends PDOException {

    function __construct($message = null, $code = 0, Exception $previous = null) {

        switch ($code) {
            case 23000:
                $message = 'Violación de restricciones de integridad';
                break;

            default: 
                break;
        }

        parent::__construct($message, $code, $previous);
    }
 }

class MyPDO extends PDO {
    public function __construct (string $dsn, string $username = null, string $password = null, array $options = array()) {
        try {
          return parent::__construct($dsn, $username, $password, $options);
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
          throw new MyPDOException($e->getMessage(), $e->getCode(), $e);
        }
    }

    public function exec (string $statement) {
        try {
          return parent::exec($statement);
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
          throw new MyPDOException($e->getMessage(), $e->getCode(), $e);
        }
    }

    // etc.
}
```

Comment: Genius! xD! Funcionan todas perfectamente, ahora, me quedo con el mapeo, porque puedo poner el mensaje de error directamente que yo quiera dedicadoa  ese error, unicamente que debo mapear muchisimos errores, otra cosa, voy añadir un trozo de codigo al final del post para ver si me puedes verificar que lo pongo correctamente, me refiero para poner mas case, lo añado al final del post, muchisimas gracias otraz vez!!.

Comment: Estoy mirando una cosa, en el mapeo que me ayudastes a resolver estoy viendo que por ejemplo el error 23000 no puede ser solo clave duplicada, dentro de este error 23000 tiene como casi 15 más, podrian ser capturados?
Por que se supone que coje el SQLSTATE, se podria coger mejor el error?https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/error-messages-server.html

Comment: Hasta donde se, vas a tener que buscar `palabras claves` en el mensaje, para poder distinguir cual de todos es.

Comment: Claro pero me resulto raro ya que, `1451` sigue siendo una `palabra clave` al igual que el `23000` porque en tu ejemplo de `case` obtenemos el `23000` y me resulto raro no coger el `1451`

Comment: Pasa que `1451`, no es devuelto por `getCode`, sino que es parte del mensaje. Mi ejemplo puse el siguiente comentario `// AQUI Analizar cual de todos los tipos es`, con esto quise decir, que falta ver cual de todos es.

Comment: Vale vale, entonces el problema del mapeo es: Cogemos el error `SQLSTATE 23000` que luego este tenga 10 problemas es diferente, en definitiva al usuario no le aclara con exactitud la brecha del problema no? Imagino que sera una de esas por las cosas que aparte de no servirme que el mapeo no se use salvo para cosas concretas

Answer (score 0):

No se si sea demasiado tarde pero, yo solucione ese problema al momento de hacer el catch de la siguiente manera:

Explico: Solamente en caso de que getCode() me retorne error 23000 guardo el string del error en una variable, luego separo ese string en un array cada vez que halla un espacio con explode(), y luego con la funcion in_array() de php miro si el codigo 1451 se encuentra en el string.

No se si sea la mejor manera, pero a mi me ha funcionado. Exitos. Dejo el codigo:

Luego del try {}

```
catch(Exception $e){
    switch ($e->getCode()) {
        case 23000:
            $serror= $e->getMessage();
            $eerror= explode(" ", $serror);

            if (in_array("1451",$eerror))
            {
                //Lo que quieres que haga para el el error 1451 que esta dentro del 23000
            }
            else
            {
                // Por si no tienes el error listado muestre el general
            }
        default:
            return $e->getMessage();
    }

}
```